# How to bulk extract outlook properties from every contact in distribution list?

Tags: outlook

Does anyone know how to bulk extract outlook properties from everyone inside a distribution list?

I can expand the distribution list by clicking the small + sign, but that only gives me first and last names, what I want is their aliases (which only available on outlook property)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry actually I just found 1 way of doing it:

1. Backup and remove everyone in your contact list
2. Open the outlook properties of the distribution list
3. Add all members of the distribution list into your contact
4. Export your contact list into excel, and the alias will be in one of the column

Feel free to post additional answer if you have better method. Thanks